# Old VB Script how to escape double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<script>
   var comment = "<%=Server.HTMLEncode(rc("comment"))%>";
</script>
```

What I tried and it didn't work:

```
var comment = "<%=Server.HTMLEncode(rc('comment'))%>";
var comment = "<%=Server.HTMLEncode(rc("""comment"""))%>";
var comment = "<%=Server.HTMLEncode(rc(" & chr(34) & "comment" & chr(34) & "))%>";
```

Also `var comment = '<%=Server.HTMLEncode(rc("comment"))%>';` doesn't work because the string that is returned might have ' in it and so the sentence breaks in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
var comment = "<%= Replace(Server.HTMLEncode(rc("comment")), """", "\""") %>";
```

This function replaces `"` with `\"`